# CSS Inheritance Generator

Tags: css

Can CSS have inheritance like OOP?

For example I have this style

```
.myButton {
background-color:#ffec64;
border:1px solid #ffaa22;
}
```

Can I define parent for color attributes? Something like

```
myYellow: #ffec64
```

So that in every styles I will just use

```
.myButton {
background-color:myYellow;
border:1px solid #ffaa22;
}
```

So that changing yellow color will only be on myYellow attribute not for every background-color attributes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use LESS : http://lesscss.org/  or SASS : http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Hmm so by default CSS doesn't have this kind of feature is it?

Comment: no, but you will have much easier life using SASS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use CSS Pre Processors like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

*Example Using [LESS variables](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature)*

```
@myYellow: #ffec64;

.myButton {
    background-color: @myYellow;
    border: 1px solid #ffaa22;
}
```

*or even you can use [LESS mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature) to inherit css class.*

```
.myCommonButton {
    background-color: @myYellow;
    border: 1px solid #ffaa22;
}

.myButton {
    .myCommonButton;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible when using CSS alone.

You can do this by using a css preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).  These allow for variables, mixins, functions and many other techniques that allow you to make CSS that is more maintainable, themable and extendable.

Once you have written your LESS or SASS you then need to compile it to standard css (in the case of LESS this can be done client-side).